# How to create a X matrix out of a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, model.matrix

I have a dataframe called "prediction_set" which contains y and all possible predictors. From this dataframe, I want to generate the y vector and the X matrix. I've tried the following code but unfortunately, it only generates an empty matrix (although it displays the column names). How can I solve this?

```
#store dataframe
prediction_set <- subset(df_clean, is.na(df_clean$lnpercapitaconsumption))

#create X matrix and y vector for prediction set

X_prediction_set <- model.matrix(lnpercapitaconsumption ~ ., prediction_set)
y_prediction_set <- prediction_set$lnpercapitaconsumption
```

A sample of my dataframe can be found below:

```
> dput(prediction_set[1:20, c(1, 74)])
structure(list(lnpercapitaconsumption = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), h_hhsize = c(1L, 3L, 
4L, 9L, 8L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 
5L, 4L)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

All your values are NA's, because you select a subset of `df_clean` with only these rows where `lnpercapitaconsumption` is NA). If you do the following, for example:

```
prediction_set$lnpercapitaconsumption <- rnorm(nrow(prediction_set))
```

(fill the variable with noise), you will see that the model matrix works as expected. Maybe you meant `!is.na()` rather than `is.na()`?

Or maybe you want to make predictions based on a training set model? In that case, you don't need the Y or a model.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The y variable consists only of NAs because I want to predict those values which are "unknown". I could create a subset containing only such rows now. However, I still couldn't find a solution to create the X matrix.

Comment: You can't. What do you need the model matrix for? You need the model matrix to create the model; but you have a model already – the one that you want to use for predicting the values...